# a completely transparent overlay with a white blank box in the middle

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I include `jquery` core and `colorbox`scripts and link the `colorbox` stylesheet too, but when I click on images that are supposed to be displayed by colorbox, I get a completely transparent overlay with a white blank box in the middle instead of the clicked image.

Is there anything I`ve missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>

<style>

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function (){
        $("img.cover").colorbox({rel: "books"});
    });//on doc ready
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <img class="cover" src="pic1.jpg" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not sure what you've missed as we can't see what you've done.

Comment: ok, I`ll include the source in a min

Comment: sorry, code included!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

HTML:

```
<a class="cover" href="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29500000/-Swag-bieber-instagram-puppy-justin-bieber-29500273-500-500.jpg">
    <img width="250" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29500000/-Swag-bieber-instagram-puppy-justin-bieber-29500273-500-500.jpg" />
</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a.cover").colorbox({rel: "books"});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/matias/6Y7cJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I also missed to place the `images` folder of the colorbox in its directory in my project. so there were no buttons and overlay.